# Does Using a Pointer as a Container Iterator Violate the Standard

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator, random-access

[Angew made a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851547/how-to-adjust-vector-iterator-to-return-struct/41851678?noredirect=1#comment70888064_41851678) that a `vector` using a raw pointer as it's iterator type was fine. That kinda threw me for a loop.

I started researching it and found that the requirement for `vector` iterators was only that they are ["Random Access Iterators"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) for which it is explicitly stated that pointers qualify:

> A pointer to an element of an array satisfies all requirements

Is the only reason that compilers even provide iterators to `vector` for debugging purposes, or is there actually a requirement I missed on `vector`?

Comment: More likely for consistency with the rest of the standard library.  `template <class Container> void doStuff(const Container& c) { for (Container::iterator i = c.begin(); i != c.end(); ++i) { ... } }`  A template like this doesn't care what type of container you use as long as it provides `iterator`, `begin` and `end`.

Comment: @0x5453 I don't understand what you're saying? Obviously the container must return iterators. I just didn't think that returning raw pointers was reasonable. Are you addressing that statement, or something else?

Comment: The tricky part is the ADL-associated namespaces of `std::vector<T>::iterator`. Pointers do not have `std` as an associated namespace. The Standard does not require iterators to have `std` as an associated namespace, though.

Comment: @MSalters I'm always misunderstanding ADL lookup, but why would using a pointer here be an issue?

Comment: @JonathanMee: Can you swap two `std::vector<T>::iterators` with unqualified `swap(it1, it2)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> § 24.2.1
>
> Since iterators are an abstraction of pointers, their semantics is a generalization of most of the semantics
> of pointers in C++. This ensures that every function template that takes iterators works as well with
> regular pointers.

So yes, using a pointer satisfies all of the requirements for a `Random Access Iterator`.

`std::vector` likely provides iterators for a few reasons

1. The standard says it should.
2. It would be odd if containers such as `std::map` or `std::set` provided iterators while `std::vector` provided only a `value_type*` pointer. Iterators provide consistency across the containers library.
3. It allows for specializations of the vector type eg, `std::vector<bool>` where a `value_type*` pointer would not be a valid iterator.

Comment: You're hinging the "The standard says it should" on the statement "iterators are an abstraction of pointers" right?

Comment: "The standard says it should" explains why there are iterators for vectors. Numbers 2 and 3 are just two possible reasons *why* the standard says it should.

Answer (score 2):

My 50 cents:

Iterators are generic ways to access *any* STL container. What I feel you're saying is: Since pointers are OK as a replacement of iterators for vectors, why are there iterators for vectors?

Well, who said you can't have duplicates in C++? Actually it's a good thing to have different interfaces to the same functionality. That should not be a problem.

On the other hand, think about libraries that have algorithms that use iterators. If vectors don't have iterators, it's just an invitation to exceptions (exceptions in the linguistic since, not programming sense). Every time one has to write an algorithm, he must do something different for vectors with pointers. But why? No reason for this hassle. Just interface everything the same way.

Comment: What operations would you be referring to that must be done differently between iterators and pointers? I can't actually think of any.

Comment: @JonathanMee I think his point is, that iterators are there just to let vector have the same interfaces available, as other classes - to prevent needing special treatment of vector class, by anyone who prefers working with iterators over pointers for everything else, for example.

Comment: @Carmageddon Can you give me an example of how you'd work differently with an iterator than you would a pointer? This is a great answer if pointers must be treated differently or function differently than iterators. But if they provide identical operators, and have identical behavior then this is not a great answer. (I've been using pointers interchangeably with iterators for years.)

Answer (score 2):

What those comments are saying is that

```
template <typename T, ...>
class vector
{
public:
    typedef T* iterator;
    typedef const T* const_iterator;
    ...
private:
    T* elems; // pointer to dynamic array
    size_t count;
    ...
}
```

is valid. Similarly a user defined container intended for use with `std::` algorithms can do that. Then when a template asks for `Container::iterator` the type it gets back *in that instantiation* is `T*`, and that behaves properly.

So the standard requires that `vector` has a definition for `vector::iterator`, and you use that in your code. On one platform it is implemented as a pointer into an array, but on a different platform it is something else. Importantly these things behave the same way in all the aspects that the standard specifies.

Comment: I believe this is the only answer that addresses the OP's real underyling question.